# Serialized Data: How to Check if byte array is Qt or Boost

Tags: qt, serialization, boost, arrays, archive

I receive raw data blocks without header information about the serialized datas origin. The only information i have is that its one out of the following: A serialized QtByteArray or a Boost Archive. Is there any way to check for a signature or similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: **No.**

The other answers are rather dangerous. What you wish to do simply cannot be done without adding some information to the serialized data that describes the type of serialization used. Remember that neither Qt's nor Boost's serialization is designed to be robust against what amounts to a malicious data stream.

Qt's serialization of a `QByteArray' is simply a 32-bit byte count followed by the data. There is no type information or anything like that.  The boost archive contains a bit more information, but still, there are absolutely no guarantees that it will fail gracefully on what amounts to a random stream of bytes. It may fail by exhausting the memory, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try to deserialize using one then the other and assume it is valid data if the operation succeed. It is not error prone, but the you can assume that the probability of some raw data being valid for both is small. Even in this case you have to try to deserialize in a specific order. Put the most probable first.